# JavaScript library to get list items based on a view using CSOM/JSOM

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom, jsom

Before I write my own, I was wondering if there are any good JS libraries for SP that can be used to get data from an SP list given the list and view name.

I know it is something anyone can do themselves but I wanted to simplify it into a generic library so you can make a call like `getListItems(listName, viewName)` and get an array of objects for each item in the list.

I like CSOM/JSOM because it gives JavaScript friendly objects of fields (i.e. a Date field yields a `Date` object) but having to write all the code every time I need to get items for a view is a  PITA.

I was going to write a library where you'd provide the list and view name and it'd return an array of objects for the rows in that view. I figured before I do that I should check if one already exists.

My Google searches yielded nothing so I thought I'd check here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get sharepoint list items array of objects by `list name` and `view name`:

**Using Javascript:**

```
function getItemsFromView(listTitle, viewTitle) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    context.load(list);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
    context.load(view);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" + view.get_viewQuery() + "</Query></View>");

            var items = list.getItems(query);

            context.load(items);
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                    return listEnumerator; // Return List Item array
                },
                function (sender, args) { alert("error in inner request: " + args.get_message()); }
        );
        },
        function (sender, args) { alert("error: " + args.get_message()); }
    );
}

//Example of usage    
var listItems = getItemsFromView("Tasks", "My Tasks");
var i = 0;
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    i++;
}
alert("items retrieved: " + i);
```

**Using CSOM:**

```
Public ListItemCollection GetSPItems(listName, viewName){

ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

List list1 = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName); 

View view = list1.Views.GetByTitle(viewName);
clientContext.Load(view);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = view.ViewQuery;
ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query); 

context.Load(items); 
context.ExecuteQuery(); 
retun items;

}

//Example of usage:

ListItemCollection listItems = GetSPItems("Tasks", "My Tasks");
```

Comment: Thanks but I am asking if there are any libraries someone has written to do this instead of having to writing the whole code every time I need it.

Comment: put JS function in external js & call external js on your page to use function,.. same make common class for CSOM function & call the method of the class..

Comment: very good! thank you! :) Now I can prepare queries as list views! :D